# jquery, c#, server validation and validation blocks

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax

Im using the ms validation blocks to validate user input posted using jquery (ajax).  Can someone give me an example of the best way to inform the user that the data does not validate.

Do i simply throw an exception and use the error event of the $.ajax function to inform the user of the issues or is there a better way of handling this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MVC, there's a good example of using the built in data annotations logic with jquery here:
http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2011/01/28/aspnet-mvc-3-client-side-validation-summary-with-jquery-validation-unobtrusive-javascript.aspx

If you're going to be doing some error handling above and beyond basic validation on the server, then personally I use the `error` event to handle critical errors (invalid permissions, server errror, etc..) and then do my validation/error checking in the `success`. If you do a lot of ajax parsing, then making simple custom json result object is somtimes handy:

```
$.ajax(..
  success : function(item) { 
    if( !item.ok ) { /* handle validation logic*/ } 
    else { /* success */ }
  }
);
```

Where your json return object could look like this

```
public class JsonResultObject
{
  public bool ok { get; set; }
  public string message { get; set; }
  public object data { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller (if MVC) you return it as follows:

```
public JsonResult Validate( CustomPostModel model )
{
    JsonResultObject result = new JsonResultObject()
    {
      ok = false,
      message = "Some custom error message here",
      data = model
    }
    return Json(result);
}
```

Comment: cool.  so you create a json wrapper object.  Seems like a good idea.  If i was just returning html i guess i could have a string property called HTML or similar as well

Comment: Yeah, its easy to vary on your needs. You don't NEED the wrapper, but it can be helpful when building a lot of json calls that provide feedback. If you wanted to simplify, you could make a convention stating: "return the string 'error' when something goes wrong, else return the object" and then you could just check for `if( item == 'error')` in your `success` block. You wouldn't get a strict server error, so it would be up to the client function to display the appropriate feedback to the user. This would remove the need for boxing up your JsonResults on the server. -cheers